# unable to connect any URL in python

Tags: python, http

Getting the below error

```
<urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

Below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
request = Request('http://google.com/')
try:
    response = urlopen(request)
    kittens = response.read()
    print kittens[559:1000] 
except URLError, e:
    print 'No kittez. Got an error code:', e
```

Comment: and what error are you getting?

Comment: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

Comment: is your machine behind any proxies? does it have a firewall?

Comment: Yes it can be can you tell how to check that, i am running it on a Linux box and my python version is Python 2.6.6

Comment: I personally don't have an idea, but you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460139/python-urllib2-giving-network-unreachable-error-if-the-url-is-https) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450776/python-always-returning-network-is-unreachable-because-of-old-ipv6-configuration) answers and hopefully you will find some solution. Hope this helps!

Comment: Add full logging to your URL request inside your code.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697963/how-to-debug-urllib2-request-that-uses-a-basic-authentication-handler Paste the full response (strip all personal information from it before you paste).